# Cannot build valid Unity3D UWP package for Windows Store, error MinVersion <= 10.0.17134.0

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, uwp, windows-store

I'm trying to create my first Windows Store app, a Unity UWP game. I have set the minimum and target OS versions in Unity to 10.0.18... and built. I've then opened the output UWP project folder and opened in Visual Studio 2019 the game's .sln project where I've set the project property's Min and Target versions to 10.0.18..., and then performed Publish > Create App Packages. When I upload my packages, I'm told:

> Package acceptance validation error:
>   ionAXXIA_0.7.603.0_Win32_Master.msix is not valid. You cannot upload
>   msix/msixbundle/msixupload packages that targets Windows MinVersion <=
>   10.0.17134.0.​

How do I set the target version?

Answer (score 0):

The target versions are recorded in the manifest, which is well explained. However, changing the values in the project Properties did not result in updating the manifest, and viewing the manifest in Studio opens the editor by default which also doesn't show the versions.

In the end I fixed the problem by right-clicking the Package.appxmanifest file in the VS solution and choosing "open with..." XML editor. The MinVersion was set to 10.0.0.0 so I bumped that up to the required, job done.

In short, the included App Manifest Designer tool is inadequate and you need to check the manifest test manually.